# Is there a way to create a field in Django so that it's constrained to be within a set of values?

Tags: django, django-models

For instance, I have a field in a model class called Role, and instead of creating a separate Role model by hand, that I then later have to write code to populate with 5 known values, is there a way to express that the Role field in my Person model can only hold those 5 known values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation on choices. http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/fields/#choices in the admin site they appear as drop down boxes automatically:).
Dean

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`choices`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) argument of the field's constructor.